# UNIX/Linux: What's the file permission number?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, windows-subsystem-for-linux, file-permissions

When I ask for file permissions on a Windows-10 WSL Ubuntu app, I do:

```
ls -ltra
```

And I get information like:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 scampsd scampsd 42034 Mar 29 15:26 Filename.cs
drwxrwxrwx 1 scampsd scampsd  4096 Mar 29 15:26 .
```

Now, as explained in [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71673088), I get information, related to the so-called "file permission number", being 644 in this case.

Is there a UNIX/Linux commandline command I can launch in order to get "644" as an answer, instead of the `rwx---...` thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only the octal code of a single file or directory, you can use `stat` (using the file `.zshrc` as an example):

```
❯ ls -ltra
...
-rw-r--r--  1 main main      4520 Jan 25 10:39 .zshrc
...

❯ stat -c '%a' .zshrc
644
```

in this case, we use `-c` to tell `stat` we want to use a custom format string, and then set our format string to `'%a'`, which prints the file permissions in octal format.

If you want an output somewhat similar to `ls`, you can do this:

```
❯ stat -c '%a %h %U %G %s %y %n' .zshrc
644 1 main main 4520 2022-01-25 10:39:26.000000000 -0800 .zshrc
```

This uses a format string that gets `stat` as close to `ls` style output as possible. Explanation, from `man stat`:

```
%a     access rights in octal (note '#' and '0' printf flags)
%h     number of hard links
%U     user name of owner
%G     group name of owner
%s     total size, in bytes
%y     time of last data modification, human-readable
%n     file name
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `stat` command:

```
mtak@rubiks:~$ stat connect.log
  File: connect.log
  Size: 6593077     Blocks: 12880      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 810h/2064d  Inode: 243067      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    mtak)   Gid: ( 1000/    mtak)
Access: 2022-01-12 15:24:31.270000000 +0100
Modify: 2021-12-02 09:28:00.430000000 +0100
Change: 2021-12-02 09:28:00.430000000 +0100
 Birth: -
```

On line 4 of the output you can see the permissions in octal form.

Or with the formatting option `%a` to get only the octal permissions:

```
mtak@rubiks:~$ stat -c '%a' connect.log
644
```

You could even fake your own ls-like output:

```
mtak@E2QJZJW2:~$ stat -c '%a %n' /bin/*
755 /bin/2to3-2.7
777 /bin/GET
777 /bin/HEAD
777 /bin/NF
```

Although, you might benefit from learning to convert between octal representation and human readable form. It's a simple addition, where:

- `r`=4
- `w`=2
- `x`=1

So `6 = 4+2 = r+w`, `5 = 4+1 = r+x` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer for macOS users. The stat binary seems different, and I don't have the `-c` option. But, nonetheless, the `-x` option does the job:

```
stats -x config
```

```
  File: "config"
  Size: 168          FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0644/-rw-r--r--)         Uid: (  501/    coil)  Gid: (   20/   staff)
Device: 1,4   Inode: 100330096    Links: 1
Access: Sun Feb  5 08:24:43 2023
Modify: Sun Feb  5 08:24:09 2023
Change: Sun Feb  5 08:24:14 2023
 Birth: Sun Feb  5 08:24:06 2023
```